# Content Security Issues with IdentityServer 4 upgrade to version 1.5

Tags: content-security-policy, identityserver4

I upgraded my Identityserver 4 to version 1.5.1  and now have content security policy errors.None of the solutions presribed so far has worked for me
I tried this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
```

but nothing worthwhile is happening

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44222140/edit to edit/update your question and add the exact error message you are seeing your browser devtools console.

Answer (score 10):

In the IdentityServer4 Samples, the class `SecurityHeadersAttribute.cs` is responsible for sending the right CSP headers. You should only add the domain name:

```
var csp = "default-src 'self';" +
                      "img-src * 'self' data: https:;" +
                      "style-src 'self' ajax.aspnetcdn.com;" +
                      "font-src 'self' ajax.aspnetcdn.com;" +
                      "script-src 'self' ajax.aspnetcdn.com;"

 // once for standards compliant browsers
 if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Security-Policy"))
 {
     context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
 }
 // and once again for IE
 if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Content-Security-Policy"))
 {
     context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Security-Policy", csp);
 }
```